# XMLHttpRequest stops sending after 6 times

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
                                var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                httpReq.addEventListener("error", function() { console.error(httpReq.status + " " + httpReq.statusCode); })
                            var dotNetUrl = "http://localhost:60005/";
                            httpReq.open("POST", dotNetUrl)
                            httpReq.send("HELLO");
})
```

After 6 clicks, requests stop sending. If I reload my extension or the server, I can send 6 more. My VB.NET application is receiving on the other end.

```
Public Async Sub CallListener()
    Await Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(Sub() Listener())
End Sub

Public Sub Listener()
    Try
        While (True)
            Dim t = hListener.GetContextAsync()
            Dim context As HttpListenerContext = t.Result()
            Dim request As HttpListenerRequest = context.Request()

            Dim stream As IO.Stream = request.InputStream
            Dim reader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(stream)
            Dim streamRTE As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

            stream.Close()
            reader.Close()

            RaiseEvent DataReceived(streamRTE)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I built a test VB.NET client to see if it was my server, but it wasn't. The client could send as many as it wanted, and the server received it. Perhaps there's some incompatibility? I simply want my Google Chrome extension to send data to my .NET application. My extension shouldn't need to receive anything.

Comment: Don't you get any net or js errors in the console? If so, could you paste them here? Also you can attach the error event handler like as follow
httpReq.addEventListener("error", function() {
  console.error(httpReq.status + " " + httpReq.statusCode);
}), but it must be done **before** send() method is fired.

Comment: No errors. Added eventlistener, but didn't see anything. Updated my code in OP.

Comment: Ok, then please set a breakpoint or write console.log("click"); after function (tab) {  and see whether it is printed. If not, then it's something with the listener of button. Also, do you have a popup when the button is clicked?

Comment: Nope. No popup. I originally had this function on a timer, but switched to "onClicked" for testing. Put `console.log("onClicked")`, and it triggers every time. However, "HELLO" only appears 6 times on my server end.

Comment: And if you add load or loadend instead of error, is the callback fired?

Comment: Can I get an example of what you mean by that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110307/discussion-between-jakub-rozek-and-user287848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the lack of response from server.

The VB code

```
Dim response As HttpListenerResponse = context.Response()
Dim responseString As String = ""
Dim b As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString)
Dim outputStream As IO.Stream = response.OutputStream
outputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
outputStream.Close()
```

Now the browser should be able to make more requests, as there will be no pending ones, because server responses.

Comment: And for any new chrome developer like me, check the `Network` tab. It was very useful in determining the status of the xhr requests.